# How to perform joins operation on mongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have two tables

```
1. Department collection
2. Employee collection
```

```
Both the table have unique _id. I have stored multiple employee ids on Department collection.

Employee Collection:
{
 _id:"EMP1",
name:"Arjun Singh",
designation:"developer"
},
{
 _id:"EMP2",
name:"Hitesh",
designation:"VTS support"
}


Department Collection:
{
 _id:"3",
name:"XYZ Department",
employeeList:["EMP1","EMP2"]
}
```

After performing mongo db joins I need the data in below format

```
{
_id:"3",
name: "XYZ Department",
 employeeList:[
{
    _id:"EMP1",
    name:"Arjun Singh",
    designation:"developer"
},
{
    _id:"EMP2",
    name:"Hitesh",
    designation:"VTS support"
}
]
}
```

please help me how to perform joins in mongoDb

Comment: You'll have to provide your attempt, and direct us to a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce exactly the output you seek.  Note that by setting the `as` field to `employeeList` it overwrites the original list with the expanded "joined" data:

```
db.department.aggregate([
{$lookup: { from: "employee", localField: "employeeList", foreignField: "_id", as: "employeeList"}}
                ]);
```